# How to call pushnotification when server want to update pass

Tags: ios6, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, passbook, apns-php

I have an interface for updating pass. When I click 'update pass', I want to call pushnotification to the pass in device. I don't know how to do this. How to do this?

Comment: What code are you using to implement the interface for updating the passbook item? What library is connecting to APNS.

Comment: I use php and Apache !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Passbook, quite a few things have to be in place in order for a push to trigger a notification on a device. From your form, you will need to implement everything to follow this flow:

1. post the data from your form to your server and update the pass record(s) in your database
2. retrieve the device pushToken(s) for the device(s) that require the updated pass from your devices table (these should be linked to the pass table with a common key)
3. connect to the production APNS using the PassID certificate that matches the `passTypeIdentifier` of the changed pass
4. send an APNS message containing an empty payload for each device
5. wait a few seconds......
6. upon receiving the push, each device will contact your web service using the '[Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988)' method
7. your web service must respond with a json dictionary containing the serial(s) of the updated pass (note only send serials relevant to the device, if you send a serial of a pass that is not installed, you will receive error log messages)
8. when the device get's your response, it will call your service again with the '[Getting Latest Version of a Pass](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988)' for the serial you sent it.
9. dynamically build the new .pkpass bundle and send as a response with the correct MIME type and 'Last-Modified' header
10. providing that a field value has changed, and that field dictionary contains a changeMessage key, a notification will show on the device. If nothing has changed, or if no changeMessage is set, the above will still happen, the pass will update but you will not see a notification.

Comment: Thank you ! I will try more !

Comment: so we send APNS message with pushToken or deviceToken ?

Comment: These are two different names for the same thing.  The `deviceToken` as referred to in the APNS docs is the `pushToken` that your web service receives when the device registers.

Comment: from my update interface that I test in mac, after I enter new values, then I call pushnotification, but no result, I don't know why !

Comment: You'll need to debug to see how far the request is getting.  After submitting the form, you can use `echo "<pre>" . print_r($variable_name, true) . "</pre>";` to print the contents of your variables to the browser.  You should be able to do this for every variable until the push is sent.  Then you will need to write to the error log to see what is going on when the device calls your web service and also monitor your device console in Xcode.

Comment: now method for Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device doesn't get called that is different from before ! why is it like that ? This is the code I use to get serial : if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "GET" && $request[4] ==="devices"){
 $deviceID = $request[5];
 $request[6] === "registrations";
    $passTypeID = $request[7];
 
 date_default_timezone_set ('Asia/Phnom_Penh');
 // Create a header with the current time
 header('Last-Modified: ' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", time()) . ' GMT+7');

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments as it is impossible to read.  There are many different reasons as to why your code is not working, but it is impossible to diagnose from a single snipped of code. The `Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device` method is initiated from the device.  If the device is not calling it, it is because it is not receiving the push. Check the console in Xcode as soon as you send the push, you should see it arrive on the device and then see it call your web service for the serials. If the push doesn't arrive, debug to see if it is being sent.

Comment: how to connect to the production APNS using the PassID certificate that matches the passTypeIdentifier of the changed pass ?

Comment: I use some codes like this : $cert = '../certificates/Certificates.pem';

Comment: stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $cert);

Comment: $ConnectAPNS = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

Comment: As you said that if push works , it will call method getting serial, so I think my push code is not yet right !

Comment: Your code above will make a connection, but it is not sending anything.  How are you packing the APNS message and sending it through this connection?

Comment: $apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $pushToken)) . chr(0) . chr(mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;

Comment: $success = fwrite($ConnectAPNS, $apns_message);

Comment: So $success should return the number of bytes transmitted to APNS.  Try debugging that variable to check that the push is being sent.  Also you might want to check `$pushToken` and `$payload` to make sure they containing what you expect.

Comment: output  of :$payload = json_encode (array("aps" => "")); is 
payload :{"aps":""} and $pushtoken also has value, push token :43401d1da3132a04f444bb70ccb0c22636a57119aa004dc815a95b61d462c2bb

Comment: method I use for getting serial of pass works before, but now it is not called from device!

Comment: If I update pass by toggling the back of pass, I will see a notification and get a new pass !

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with my pushnotification that it cannot call device !

Comment: `error_log('Stream Response: ' . print_r($success, true), 0);`

Comment: I get : Stream Response: 47

Comment: I wait so long time, but no push notification to update pass !

Comment: Are you certain that the pushToken is correct. Try deleting all passes, clearing your devices table and install a new pass. The push is being sent but is not arriving on the device so most likely cause is a stale or wrong pushToken. Device IDs and tokens change regularly - they are not fixed.

Comment: yes, pushToken is correct as the same as from database ! in php_error.log, I also get : [01-May-2013 04:55:22 Europe/Berlin] 01-05-2013 0404:5555:2222: APNS Message successfully sent to push token 43401d1da3132a04f444bb70ccb0c22636a57119aa004dc815a95b61d462c2bb

Comment: or pushnotification will push for https and cannot for http ? I still test with http; not yet with https !

Comment: Delete the push token from the database and get the device to re-register - even though the token matches what you have in your database, your device may have rotated it's ID and token.

Comment: Yes, I did so and test another push !

Comment: in order to update a new pass, I save new data to pass table and then I call pushnotification.php by including it !

Comment: in php_error.log, I see this: [01-May-2013 05:54:25 Europe/Berlin] 01-05-2013 0505:5454:2525: APNS Message successfully sent to push token 43401d1da3132a04f444bb70ccb0c22636a57119aa004dc815a95b61d462c2bb

Comment: how to set condition for push notification in order to stop pushnotification for unchanged pass ?

Comment: You should only be calling the APNS server in response to your update form.  But it looks like you are calling it every time the web service is sent.  I would suggest putting your update form and APNS call in a separate file (e.g. update.php) since triggering updates should be done independently to the web service.

Comment: yes, now I only call APNS from update form and I get only 1 success push message in php_error.log, but push notification still not shows !

Comment: the pass is changed a lot of time , but I cannot get if-modified-since ([01-May-2013 06:12:41 Europe/Berlin] if-modified-since: 
)

Comment: I put this too:  // Tell PHP to use UTC
 date_default_timezone_set ('UTC');

Comment: // Create a header with the current time
 header('Last-Modified: ' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", time()) . ' GMT + 7');

Comment: That is why the getting latest version pass method always gets response 200 even the unchanged pass !

Comment: I think your problem is one more of poor design of your web service code. Calls appear to be taking the incorrect path through your code.  As I mentioned before.  You should try to step back from the screen, perhaps print out your code, and try to see exactly what path these calls are taking to understand why they are produce the results you are seeing.  Because so far, you have developed your service by adding a bit here and changing bit there but some of the later changes may have broken earlier fixes. With the knowledge you have now, it may be better to build a completely new file.

Comment: now I add 1 more connectAPNS, and getting serial method is called.  $ConnectAPNS = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

Comment: $ConnectAPNS1 = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

Comment: $success = fwrite($ConnectAPNS, $apns_message);
$success1 = fwrite($ConnectAPNS1, $apns_message);

Comment: so I need to  put this to array and send ?